# Jenkins/Maven Artifactory Error

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I have a Jenkins/Maven build as well as Artifactory. All instances run in AWS EC2. Here what is happening. I have had a dozen successful builds but when the IP has since changed. I made the changes in Jenkins to our new FQDN but for some reason the old FQDN is getting picked up somewhere. He is the console output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [buildinfo] Properties file found at         '/tmp/buildInfo626490319749387713.properties'
[INFO] Initializing Artifactory Build-Info Recording
[HUDSON] Collecting dependencies info
[INFO]  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MS2.0 Security 0.0.14-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: http://artifactory_old:8081/artifactory/plugins-release/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://artifactory_old:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
```

The problem is the address above is not what I have configured globally and I have no idea where the old address is coming from.
Any insight would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Are you using the Artifactory Jenkins plugin? If not, where do you configure Artifactory URL?

Comment: Yes, using the plugin and I verified that I have the correct information entered in that portion of the build environment. I'm almost wondering if I should remove the plugin and reinstall it

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the `Artifactory servers` part of the Jenkins System Configuration screen.

Comment: so I actually figured out the problem early this morning after sleeping on it.

Comment: opps, hit enter to quick. I removed the jenkins artifactory plugin and reinstalled it. that fixed the issue.

Comment: My guess is somewhere in the plugin the original IP get's hardcoded in the pom.xml repository section. Once I reinstalled it and ran a test build it defaulted to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 I then changed the repository address to my artifactory server in the Artifact Resolver global jenkins configuration